# Accessing database content based on /variable

Tags: mysql, variables

So I am a bit new to MYSQL and I've been learning allot more about relational databases but I am a bit stumped with one subject in mind. I notice allot of sites have things like domain.tld/variable. I understand how this works by using /?variable=name but most users would never use that. So how does one go about letting users pull content based on the principal listed?

Comment: are you asking how to get to parameter passing, say on the server, like in PHP ? so that the server can respond with the relevant data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that has nothing to do with databases.

When the url is accessed, [url rewriting](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) is used to change the url behind the scenes. While the user enters `domain.com/data`, the php script (or anything else) at `domain.com?variable=data` is opened.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense! Thank you! Any chance you could point me in the right direction on learning more about the rewrite rules? Very much appreciated :)

Comment: I only had a quick glance at it, but this beginners guide might help you: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Well thank you! I think that pretty much hit the nail on the head.